# Trying to get a literal into a pointer in Golang

Tags: go, methods, struct, interface

To ease testing of the code I'm responsible for testing, I'm refactoring my team's `LogHandler`.

They had something like this:

```
type LogHandlerSt struct {
    path        string
    fileName    string
    projectName string
}

var (
    //Instance The project instance of log handler.
    Instance LogHandlerSt
    //OnResponseError A function that can be set to be called on response error.
    OnResponseError func(context interface{}, response *http.Response)
    //includeStack Will include all lines with the strings below in the debug stack.
    includeStack = []string{"apiserver_sdk", "ezdineserver_sdk"}
)

//CreateLogHandler Creates and assigns a log handler instance for use by the project.
func CreateLogHandler(path string, fileName string, projectName string) LogHandlerSt {
    Instance = LogHandlerSt{path: path, fileName: fileName, projectName: projectName}.
        fmt.Println("Log files are in \"" + path + "\"")
    return Instance
}

//log Logs a message given the type of message and the message itself.
func (handler *LogHandlerSt) log(logType string, errMsg string) {
    fmt.Println(errMsg)
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(handler.path+"/"+handler.fileName+" "+time.Now().Format("2006-01-02")+".log", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()
    if _, err = logFile.WriteString(`
` + logType + " " + time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000") + `: ` + errMsg + "\n"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    logFile.Sync()
}

//GetProjectNames Gets the projects to use for the log handler instance. Usually used for the debug stack.
func (handler *LogHandlerSt) GetProjectNames() []string {
    var projectNames = []string{handler.projectName}
    projectNames = append(projectNames, includeStack...)
    return projectNames
}

//LogError Logs an error given information.
func (handler *LogHandlerSt) LogError(errMsg string) {
    handler.log("Error", errMsg)
}

//LogWarning Logs a warning given information.
func (handler *LogHandlerSt) LogWarning(errMsg string) {
    handler.log("Warn", errMsg)
}

//LogInfo Logs some information.
func (handler *LogHandlerSt) LogInfo(errMsg string) {
    handler.log("Info", errMsg)
}
```

Many methods in the code base under test use these functions, on `Instance`. To remedy this, I introduced a struct `Logger` thusly:

```
// Logger provides a generic implementation of the required methods.
//  Provided for testing purposes
type Logger interface {
    LogError(errMessage string)
    LogWarning(errMessage string)
    LogInfo(errMessage string)
}
```

Instincts, especially from Java, told me to change declaration of that `Instance` to a `Logger`. This, of course, did nothing, as `Logger` was an instance whereas the methods were on a `*Logger`. So, I changed to `Instance *Logger` and refactored `CreateLogHandler` to take care of the compile-time error I just created:

```
//CreateLogHandler Creates and assigns a log handler instance for use by the project.
func CreateLogHandler(path string, fileName string, projectName string) LogHandlerSt {
    Instance = &LogHandlerSt{path: path, fileName: fileName, projectName: projectName}
        fmt.Println("Log files are in \"" + path + "\"")
    return Instance
}
```

I get told:

```
cannot use LogHandlerSt literal (type *LogHandlerSt) as type *Logger in assignment:
*Logger is pointer to interface, not interface
```

**WHY NOT**, and what can I do about this?

Comment: I even tried writing that literal to a temp variable, and then assigning `Instance` its address.

Comment: _" as `Logger` was an instance whereas the methods were on a `*Logger`"_. Stop right there. `Logger` is an interface. Methods are "not on an interface". Concrete implementations have a concrete receiver type, which will be `*LogHandlerSt`, not `*Logger`, nor `Logger`. Also `LogHandlerSt` does not implement `Logger`, only `*LogHandlerSt` as methods are defined to have pointer receiver.

Comment: What will I have to do to make `LogHandlerSt`,`Logger` such that `LogHandlerSt` implements `Logger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " as `Logger` was an instance whereas the methods were on a `*Logger`".

Stop right there. `Logger` is an interface. Methods are "not on an interface". Concrete implementations have a concrete receiver type, which will be `*LogHandlerSt`, not `*Logger`, nor `Logger`. Also `LogHandlerSt` does not implement `Logger`, only `*LogHandlerSt` as methods are defined with pointer receiver.

If you introduce `Logger`, this is how you may use it:

```
var Instance Logger

func CreateLogHandler(path string, fileName string, projectName string) Logger {
    Instance = &LogHandlerSt{
        path: path,
        fileName: fileName,
        projectName: projectName
    }
    fmt.Println("Log files are in \"" + path + "\"")
    return Instance
}
```

Since only `*LogHandlerSt` implements `Logger`, you have to assign a pointer to `Instance`.

Note that you should rarely (if ever) use a pointer to interface (such as `*Logger`). Instead the pointer to the concrete type should be wrapped in an interface value.

Comment: It didn't work. It gave me the same error as before: `cannot use Instance (type Logger) as type LogHandlerSt in return argument`. What do I need to do to implement `Logger`?!

Comment: @MikeWarren Please do note that I changed the return type of `CreateLogHandler`. Although I don't know why you need to return that, you could just access it via the `Instance` variable.

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm just the tester! lol I have to see if the boss OKs these changes to the code base first.

Comment: He approved them